# fetch v8 : "-bash: fetch: command not found"

Tags: ubuntu, installation, javascript, fetch

I asked this question 1day ago in `stackoverflow` but there is no answer for it until now, but I need it now, So I asked it here again:

I want to install `JavaScript` on my ARM-based(arm7) board with Armbian 5.3(Ubuntu-Server 16.04). As it says here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/ I need to install `depot_tools` and as it says here: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html I did this commands:

```
cd /home/m
mkdir depot_tools
    git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
   `export PATH="$PATH:/home/m/depot_tools"`
```

Then I tried : `fetch v8` but I got:

`"-bash: fetch: command not found"`

Comment: Normally when you clone, it creates the folder for you.  See if fetch is in `/home/m/depot_tools/depot_tools`

Comment: @Paul: yes, there is a file named `fetch` there

Comment: Can you go into `/home/m/depot_tools/depot_tools` and run `fetch v8` from in that path? Note: You may need to `chmod +x` to make fetch executable (if it is not yet done already). (or maybe `./fetch v8`)

Comment: @Darius: thank you it works `fetch v8` . So how should I change this line: ` --enable-javascript --with-v8-path=/path/to/v8 `

Comment: Also this is the result after running`fetch v8` command:

Running: gclient root
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "managed": False,
    "name": "v8",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads

Comment: what does it to? should I wait for it?

Comment: It stopped at this command ` ' Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads ` ...it seems nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These commands:

```
cd /home/m/depot_tools
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

will clone the tools into `/home/m/depot_tools/depot_tools`

So you need to either adjust your path to match:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/m/depot_tools/depot_tools"
```

Or move everything to the folder above so that your current path is correct:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
mv /home/m/depot_tools/* /home/m/depot_tools
```

(the `shopt` command will make sure `*` matches hidden files, so the git folders will be moved too)

Comment: Thank you paul, may you check the comments of question too?

Comment: @user145959 if you do the mv suggested here, the you can follow the instructions as is

Comment: OK, I did edit my question entirely and removed and tried the steps from first, so what will happen after this step?

Comment: @user145959 Please don't do this, if you have a different.question open a new one.  This answer no longer makes sense.  I'll revert your edit.

Comment: Crap, I can't on mobile, please revert your edit and open a new question

Comment: are there any options for revert?

Comment: OK I did edit my questio

Answer (score -2):

Just Type in your terminal this

~/path/to/depot_tools/fetch

And then type what you what fetch to do e.g chromium or ios